# AngularJS directive template not updating if scope is populated via ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to give this question as precise a title as I could.
I'm pretty new to AngularJS but I'm stomped on this issue. I tried to make a jsfiddle to better illustrate my issue but it relies on too many separate files. And alas it is not online yet, so bear with the verbosity. :)
So basically I have an app I built with `yeoman init angular`, and my `app.js` looks like this:

```
"use strict"

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/lineup", {
        templateUrl: "views/lineup.html",
        controller: "LineupCtrl"
    })
    //other routes
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
})
.directive("playerlist", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: false,
        scope : {},
        templateUrl : "views/directives/playerlist.html",
        controller : function($scope) {
            $.get("/players")
            .success(function(players) {
                $scope.players = players;
            });
        },
        replace : true
    }
});
```

My `index.html` picks up `app.js` and has an anchor that references `#/lineup`, which effectively opens `views/lineup.html`; to simplify things, let's assume the latter only contains the (custom) `<playerlist></playerlist>` tag.
Inside the directive's controller function I'm sure that `$.get("/players")` works as it should because I can see from chrome's network tab that the response comes through correctly as an array of players.
Finally, my `views/directives/playerlist.html` has the code that replaces the `<playerlist>` tag, which follows:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Strength</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="player in players">
            <td>{{player.first_name}} {{player.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{player.age}}</td>
            <td>{{player.role}}</td>
            <td>{{player.strength}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My idea was to make the "playerlist" directive independent from `LineupCtrl` for I might want to reuse it elsewhere in the project.
Ok so here goes: when I click on the anchor that loads `#/lineup` the first time, the `tbody` element of the above table is empty (no rows appended to it); the funny thing is, when I click on it a second time, the table is correctly populated with the players I get with the `$.get("/players")` instruction. I suspect this is due to the slight lag that occurs between the rendering of playerlist.html and the $scope.players variable being assigned. But isn't that the whole point of an angular app? That when scope variables change the respective views (and their templates) are updated?
Please help!
Cheers,
Andrea

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whenever you update scope variables outside of an angular function, you need to tell angular that something changed. See [`scope.$apply`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope).

```
$.get("/players")
.success(function(players) {
   $scope.$apply(function () {
     $scope.players = players;
   });
});
```

On a different note, angular has a built in [ajax service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), so there is no need to use jQuery. A good explanation can be found in the tutorial: [5 - XHRs & Dependency Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Comment: Thanks for your quick and precise reply! That is exactly what I needed! I'd upvote it if I could, but unfortunately I lack the reputation... :(
About your side note: I will investigate the use of angular's built-in ajax service. I used jQuery because the underlying model layer relies on a locally-running node server, which fetches data off a local mysql db.

Comment: I can abstract from it by simply invoking `$.get("/players")` because in another file (namely `lib.js`) I have the function `$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options) {
    options.url = "http://localhost:3000" + options.url;
    options.crossDomain = true;
    options.async = false;
    return "jsonp";
});`

(cross domain is required since my app runs in localhost:3501, yeoman's default server, and node runs on localhost:3000). I will stick to jQuery until I find a way to implement the same thing in pure angular (I find the learning curve to be pretty steep).

Comment: P.S. right now if I issue `$http.get("/players")` it will look for `http://localhost:3501/players`, which does not exist.
Thanks again! Cheers!

Comment: @AndreaAloi That sounds like quite a setup! ;)  Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the very succinct answer, and example.  This was exactly what I needed.