# Angular not working properly in MVC app

Tags: angularjs

I am integrating angularJS with MVC. Since the code is long, I'll just put the important bits here:

```
<html ng-app="appname">
...
                <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
                    <p>The Item Name is {{greeting.total_hits}}</p>
                    <p>The Brand Name is {{greeting.max_score}}</p>
                </div>
...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
```

Angular is loading and showing up in the loaded scripts. When I run the app, the handlebars are gone, but I just get blank values.

In the javascript below, the web service is returning values correctly, and the alert is showing the proper value that I expect.

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {

      var url = <a long string to my data>

      $.get(url, function (data) {
          $scope.greeting = data;
          alert($scope.greeting.max_score);
      });
  }]);
```

The values are decimal. Do I maybe need to format something special to display them? Why am I getting blank values?

Comment: Try removing the `$.get()` call to populate your greeting object and use static values instead.

Comment: Looks like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984777/angularjs-directive-template-not-updating-if-scope-is-populated-via-ajax) is the same problem.